# How to building an onError() that will catch an error message on cakephp?

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I am not to experience with cakephp or programing, but what i am trying to do is delete a record from the database and when deleted redirect to the same page and if you cant delete the record because of a constrain foreign key just by pass the error:

```
SQL Error: 1451: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

and redirect to the same page with a nice error message for the user. instead of the error message above.

```
enter code here
```

I was able to accomplish the delete part but I cant by pass the error message  **SQL Erro: 1451** when I cant delete the record.

This is my function

```
    function admin_delete ($id, $residence_hall_id){
        if ($this->ResidenceHall->delete($id))  {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Item was deleted', 'success');
        }else{
            $this->Session->setFlash('Item was not deleted', 'error');
        }
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'residence_halls', 'action'=>'index', $residence_hall_id, 'admin'=>true));
    }
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use deleteAll() or just remove the database foreign key contraint from residanceHall models table. AS delete all will remove all the associated record with that model.The error that you are getting this is just due to there are some records in other table for which its id is being used for associating with reference table.

Comment: I dont think  I asked the right question but i got it working. so under the model i added var $hasMany = array('Resident'); and that got it to work. Thank you for your time.